# cx_Freeze with python packages (not just one module)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, executable, cx-freeze

All of the cx_Freeze examples are for one file (module). I need to make an executable for an entire python package. Why is that hard to make?

Here's my directory:

```
test1/
  __init__ 
  __main__
```

The way I run this from the command line is by using the following cmd

```
python -m test1
```

`__init__` is empty and `__main__` just have a simple `print` statement.
I am using python 3.5.1 but I can switch to python 3.4 if that would fix the problem

Here is my `setup.py` for win64

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

build_exe_options = {"packages": ['test1'],
                     "include_files": []
                    }
executables = [
                Executable("__main__")
              ]
setup(
    name = "Foo",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Help please!",
    author = "me",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = executables
)
```

Update:
1- see the comment below for solution for this approach
2- switch to pyinstaller because it can produce one exe file not a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freezing a whole package doesn' t make sense because to create an executable binary you will want a Python script that can be run *standalone* from the command line. A package normally isn't started out-of-the-box but would get imported by another module.

However you can always import a package in your script so when you freeze it the package gets included in your distribution.

So do something like this:

```
test1/
  __init__ 
  __main__
run_test.py
```

**run_test.py** now imports test1 and starts your function that does whatever you want.

```
import test1
run_the_whole_thing()
```

**Note:** You will need to change your Executable in the *setup.py* to `run_test.py`.

Comment: That's actually what I did. Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the solution. Also be aware that`cxFreze` will not build "one file" executable as `pyInstaller` does, but put along with executable created file a series of DLL that mainly run Python If this is still not good, you can build a MSI package as Windows installer. This will build a `msi` package, default in a `dist/` directory. To do that, run `cxfreeze` using the `build_msi` instead of simple `build`.